# HABTM association with Strong Parameters is not saving user in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters, has-and-belongs-to-many

User model:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :events
```

Event model:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

Users controller:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:role, {:event_ids => []})
```

Events controller:

```
params.require(:event).permit(:subject, :location, :date, :time, :all_day, :reminder, :notes, {:users_ids => []})
```

My form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@event) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :subject %>
    <%= f.input :location %>
    <%= f.input :date %>
    <%= f.input :time %>
    <%= f.association :users %>
    <%= f.input :all_day %>
    <%= f.input :reminder %>
    <%= f.input :notes %>

    <%= f.button :submit, :class =>"btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

I want to be able to choose a user from a list and save that user to the database.  But I am getting the following message in my console when I try to create a new Event:

```
Unpermitted parameters: user_ids
```

Do I have my setup incorrect?  Am I not passing in the correct instance variables to the form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ugh...details details!

How it was previously:

```
params.require(:event).permit(:subject, :location, :date, :time, :all_day, :reminder, :notes, {:users_ids => []})
```

How it should be:

```
params.require(:event).permit(:subject, :location, :date, :time, :all_day, :reminder, :notes, {:user_ids => []})
```

Notice that :users_ids should actually be :user_ids!

Comment: Ha! You beat me to it.

Answer (score 5):

Or you can simply use shorthand syntax like this.

```
params.require(:event).permit(:subject, :location, :date, :time, :all_day, :reminder, :notes, user_ids: [])
```

Notice: `user_ids: []` instead of `{:user_ids => []}`

Answer (score 2):

Attribute from simple_form: **user_ids**

Symbol in #permit: **users_ids**

You've added an s, remove that and you should be good to go as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a Rails 3 installation before. I upgraded to Rails 4. The select just passed a string, not an association. Thus the syntax proposed did not work. I simply had to allow `user_ids`. I.e.:

```
params.require(:event).permit(:subject, :location, :date, :time, :all_day, :reminder, :notes, :user_ids)
```

It seems Rails 4 changed the behavior.