# Rails JSON_API create Book with list of Genres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json-api

I'm trying to write my test to ensure creating a new `book` with `genres` assigned to it works.

I am using Active Model Serializer with the JSON_API structure (http://jsonapi.org/)

### Book Model File

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author, class_name: "User"
  has_and_belongs_to_many :genres
end
```

### Genre Model File

```
class Genre < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end
```

### Book Serializer file

```
class BookSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :adult_content, :published

  belongs_to :author
  has_many :genres
end
```

### Test Sample Data

```
def setup
    ...
    @fantasy = genres(:fantasy)

    @newbook = {
      title: "Three Little Pigs",
      adult_content: false,
      author_id: @jim.id,
      published: false,
      genres: [{title: 'Fantasy'}]
    }
end
```

### Test Method

```
test "book create - should create a new book" do
    post books_path, params: @newbook, headers: user_authenticated_header(@jim)
    assert_response :created
    json = JSON.parse(response.body)
    puts "json = #{json}"
    assert_equal "Three Little Pigs", json['data']['attributes']['title']
    genre_data = json['data']['relationships']['genres']['data']

    puts "genre_data = #{genre_data.count}"
    assert_equal "Fantasy", genre_data
end
```

### Book Strong Params

```
def book_params
    params.permit(:title, :adult_content, :published, :author_id, :genres)
end
```

### Test Result (console response)

```
# Running:

......................................................json = {"data"=>{"id"=>"1018350796", "type"=>"books", "attributes"=>{"title"=>"Three Little Pigs", "adult-content"=>false, "published"=>false}, "relationships"=>{"author"=>{"data"=>{"id"=>"1027431151", "type"=>"users"}}, "genres"=>{"data"=>[]}}}}
genre_data = 0
F

Failure:
BooksControllerTest#test_book_create_-_should_create_a_new_book [/Users/warlock/App_Projects/Raven Quill/Source Code/Rails/raven-quill-api/test/controllers/books_controller_test.rb:60]:
Expected: "Fantasy"
  Actual: []


bin/rails test test/controllers/books_controller_test.rb:51



Finished in 1.071044s, 51.3518 runs/s, 65.3568 assertions/s.

55 runs, 70 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

As you can see from my JSON console log, it appears my genres are not being set(need to scroll to the right in the test output above).

Please ignore this line:

```
assert_equal "Fantasy", genre_data
```

I know that's wrong. At the moment, the json is showing `genre => {data: []}` (empty array), that's the thing I'm trying to solve at the moment.

How do I go about creating a book with genres in this case, any ideas? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just sad...third time this week, I am answering my own question.

I finally found the answer from this Stackoverflow question:

[HABTM association with Strong Parameters is not saving user in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24820249/habtm-association-with-strong-parameters-is-not-saving-user-in-rails-4)

Turns out my strong parameters need to be:

```
def book_params
    params.permit(:title, :adult_content, :published, :author_id, {:genre_ids => []})
end
```

Then my test data can be:

```
@fantasy = genres(:fantasy)

@newbook = {
  title: "Three Little Pigs",
  adult_content: false,
  author_id: @jim.id,
  published: false,
  genre_ids: [@fantasy.id]
}
```

Update my test method to:

```
test "book create - should create a new book" do
    post books_path, params: @newbook, headers: user_authenticated_header(@jim)
    assert_response :created
    json = JSON.parse(response.body)
    assert_equal "Three Little Pigs", json['data']['attributes']['title']
    genre = json['data']['relationships']['genres']['data'].first['title']
    assert_equal "Fantasy", genre
end
```

Now my test passes.